# Pandas: give group-key as argument to function in groupby.apply

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with a dataset `df_cities` containing the following columns:

```
city_name, country_name, population, language
```

I have the following function for sorting the table based on if the country is in some list:

```
special_countries = ['Morocco', 'Turkey', 'Japan' ]

def sort_function(df, country_name):
    if country_name in special_countries:
         return df.sort_values(by='population')
    else:
         return df
```

Next, I want to use groupby to apply this sorting:

```
df_cities.groupby('country_name').apply(sort_function, kwargs={'country_name': x})
```

This ofcourse doesnt work since I have not declared x anywhere. My question is: How can I provide the key of the group (in this case country_name) as an argument to the function I am passing in the .apply()?

Comment: it would be helpful if you can provide an example of your table so we can work on it. Thanks

Comment: Try `pd.concat([sort_function(df, i) for i, df in df_cities.groupby('country_name')])` ..?

Comment: Try this : `df_agg= df_cities.groupby(['country_name']).agg({'count':sum})` 
    `df_agg.apply(lambda x: x.order(ascending=False))`